"Unable to verify app" problem, and I can't see my developer account in "VPN & Device Management" section
Xcode error output
'Can't verify app' alert on iOS
And I can't see any thing in "VPN & Device Management" section. Even I change the account, and the account appears, the "Verify" button can't work still.
I've tried many ways to fix this, including rebooting device, using different developer account, re-adding developer certificate, turning-on-and-off developer mode on iPhone, un-registering my iPhone from Developer website, switching to beta iOS channel, switching VPN to proxy mode (because I'm living in China, some servers might not work here), but they all can't fix this.

Question solved, just reboot the mac.
